# How to use f-strings to display a list of user inputs in python

Tags: python

I am new to list and index and I am trying to create a list of inputs from the user and distribute that list as an output but I keep running into the error "f string: expecting {"  Would I even be able to distribute the user's inputs from the grocery_list this way?

```
grocery_list = []

while True:
  try:
    item = (input("Enter an item for your grocery list. Press <ENTER> when done: "))
    grocery_list.append(item)
    if len(item) == 0:
      break
  except EOFError:
    break
    print ()
    

num_of_items = len(grocery_list) -1
print (num_of_items)

print ('Welcome to the Grocery List Program.')
print ()
for col in range (45):
  print ('=', end='')
  print (f'You have {num_of_items} items on your grocery list.')
for col in range (45):
  print ('=', end='')
print()

print (f' ---- {item[0][0]:>22} { ---- {item[1][0]:>1}')
print (f' ---- {item[0][1]:>22} { ---- {item[1][1]:>1}')
print (f' ---- {item[0][2]:>22} { ---- {item[1][2]:>1}')
print (f' ---- {item[0][3]:>22} { ---- {item[1][3]:>1}')
print (f' ---- {item[0][4]:>22} { ---- {item[1][4]:>1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you didnt do the bracketing properly, you have an extra open bracket.

```
print (f' ---- {item[0][0]:>22} { ---- {item[1][0]:>1}')
                                /\
                                ||
```

It should look like this.

```
print (f' ---- {item[0][0]:>22} ---- {item[1][0]:>1}')
```

Comment: Probably good to add that if OP wants to write a `{` or a `}` in a f-string they need to be repeated. `print(f"{{some_text{{}}"`-> `{some_text{}`